# XAMPP file create denied

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xampp

I'm encountering issues while trying to create files in the /opt/lampp/htdocs/ directory in XAMPP. I want to change the permissions of the directory, but when I cannot.

Error msg:

> Unable to write file '/opt/lampp/htdocs/index.html' (NoPermissions (FileSystemError): Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/opt/lampp/htdocs/index.html')

Additional Information:

- XAMPP Version: 8.0.30-0
- Operating System: linux ubuntu

Answer (score -1):

Probably a persmission problem.

First, try to grant read, write and execute permission for everybody  to the /opt/lampp/htdocs/ folder: `chmod 777 /opt/lampp/htdocs/`

If works, take a look at XAMPP htdocs Permission issue and Fix in Ubuntu: https://www.computernetworkingnotes.com/linux-tutorials/xampp-htdocs-permission-issue-and-fix-in-ubuntu.html

If not helps, maybe you have your partition mounted with read only option? Can you share your `/etc/fstab` file contents or the output of the `mount` command?